# Android Youtube Data Api Automatically fetch subtitles by location from Playlist

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am fetching playlist with Youtube Data Api in my android app. The videos in this list have subtitles in different languages.

For these videos, I can fetch the video titles by language, but I cannot provide automatic subtitle language selection. Is there a way for this in Youtube Data Api?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by:

> automatic subtitle language selection

giving subtitles in the same language as the title then you also have the language for both title and subtitle when you retrieve them from the YouTube Data API v3 and can make the "automatic" thing on your own with this data.

It's unclear whether or not you had a look to [Captions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) and [Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download)